# Slide Down layout, onClickListner is not working properly

Tags: android, button, layout, slide, uislider

I am using slide translate animation, which is working fine. but the problem is when the layout slides down, `Onclicklistener` is not working at the new position, instead, it is taking the `Click` function at the previous position only.
here is my code

```
TranslateAnimation animWindow = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,0, 120 );
animWindow.setDuration(1000);
animWindow.setFillAfter(true);
DpGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
DpGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
DpInfoWindowLayout.setAnimation(animWindow);
```

Comment: post your full code

Comment: I am using DpInfoWindowLayout.setOnclickLister. When the layout slides down it takes click on previous position